# Slide Out Bar with sub categories in swift

Tags: ios, swift

There are some rows in table view. Each row opens a new view. Now I want to show some sub categories on click of Particular row. each of this sub category opens different view. I am using only 1 section. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Simply do this.**

```
class CategoriesListViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var filterCategories = [CategoryViewModel]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    tfSearch.placeholder = LocalizeKey.search.localized        
    getCategories()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

extension CategoriesListViewController : UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filterCategories.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CategoryCellTableView
    let category = filterCategories[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    if let controller : SubCategoriesListViewController = ViewControllerManager.shared.find() {
        controller.selectedCategory = self.filterCategories[indexPath.row]
        self.pushViewController(controller : controller)
    }
}
```

**Sub-Categories will be subclassed from the main categories and override the table view selection methods and do whatever you want to do.**

```
class SubCategoriesListViewController: CategoriesListViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var filterCategories = [CategoryViewModel]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let controller = DifferentViewController()
    self.pushViewController(controller : controller)
}
```